# replacing ubuntu with windows 10

Tags: system-installation

I am making a new PC and I am going to see if steam works on ubuntu before installing windows 10. Because in the past, Steam hasn't worked on my ubuntu engines. So if it dosen't work, I want to wipe the SSD and replace ubuntu with windows 10. Like ubuntu, can you wipe the disk and install in the windows setup?

Comment: yes, win10 will wipe the drive. or can be installed to the current partitions. Windows can read ext partitions so will think they are blank.

Comment: I would install Windows 10 first and then Ubuntu along side it. The reason being Windows 10 can flash BIOS and update drivers whilst Linux support for flashing BIOS (led by Dell IIRC) is just starting to arrive now. Many new PC's require BIOS flashing at least once over the first 12-18 months of life.